# Spring: no suitable message converter

Tags: android, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to use Spring for a GET http request.

My main class:

```
    final String url = getString(R.string.myurl);

        // Populate the HTTP Basic Authentitcation header with the username and password
        String Usn = "username";
        String ww = "password";

        HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(Usn, ww);
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        System.out.println("Headers: " + requestHeaders.toString());

        // Create a new RestTemplate instance
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());


        try {
            // Make the network request
            Log.d(TAG, url);
            ResponseEntity<CatMessage> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), CatMessage.class);
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

With CatMessage class:

```
public class CatMessage {

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String message;
    public int code;

}
```

What i should get back, because i am using not working username and password combination (and this server part works fine), is:

> {
>
> ```
> "message": "You are not authorized to use this service",
> "code": 5201
> ```
>
> }

I thought this should work, because i am pretty much copying the basic auth [project of Spring for Android](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-basic-auth/client)

But what happens is a problem with the parsing (i think). Of course I have included the Jackson and Spring dependencies, so i do not expect my problems to be there. But I expect a very small JSON, have a well-mapped model of it (CatMessage) and have my Jackson files included so i thought this should work... but i get the error below:

> 02-22 00:13:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): Caused by:
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract
>   response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type
>   [org.springframework.android.basicauth.CatMessage] and content type
>   [text/html] 02-22 00:13:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:79)
>   02-22 00:13:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:655)
>   02-22 00:13:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:641)
>   02-22 00:13:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484)
>   02-22 00:13:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
>   02-22 00:13:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):   at o
>   rg.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)

Does anyone have an idea where my problem could be? It sucks to work for hours on something that seems so easy...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK and the only explanation that I can think of is that the service you are calling

1. Does not produce JSON content.
2. It produces JSON but sets a `Content-Type` response header of `text/json` or something like this (the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` only knows about `application/json` by default).

Can you check the `Content-Type` response header (as this is the very thing used by the `RestTemplate` to select the proper `HttpMessageConverter`) ?

Comment: I think my content type is good: Content-Type: application/json. Is there a way i can print the request before it is parsed into an object? so i can check if indeed my JSON is what i expect? Whenever i throw the URL in a browser it gives exact the JSON i posted...

Comment: It's not the request that is parsed, it's the response. The simplest approach would be to debug it.

Comment: Yeah i meant response, in my comment above. I don't get it working to debug the responses, i am using a device and not an emulator... Do you know any other way? thanks.

Comment: Just try to perform the exact same request with `curl` or some graphic rest client and see if there's anything fishy with that response...